Bound on dimension of centralizer of algebras
First I will write the problem:

Assume $A$ is a simple ring (has no non trivial two sided ideals) and is left Artinian, denote $F$ to be its center, and $B \subseteq A$ a subring containing $F$, if $A$ as a $B$_module is generated by $n$ elements, show that $dim_F C_A(B) \le n$

I am fairly stuck on the problem as I don't see how to proceed towards solving it, I first tried to solve it in the case where $B$ is a simple subring and tried to use the "Centralizer theorem" but I couldn't force the conditions to apply, the condition on $A$ being left Artinian is also unknown to me and I don't know how am I supposed to use that.
I will write my work so far although it is little:
Assume $A=Bx_1+\dots+ Bx_n$ and $dim_F C_A(B)=m$ and $y_1,\dots, y_m$ a basis for $C_A(B)$, since $y_i \in A$ we must have for suitable $a_{ij}$ that
$y_i= \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}x_j$, these $y_i$ must be $F$ linearly independant, hence $\hat{F}. Y=0$ has no solution for $\hat{F} \in F^m$, now since $Y=AX$ where $A=[a_{ij}]$ we know that $\hat{F}A$ can't fall in the $F$_module of $I=\{[r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n]| r_1x_1+r_2x_2+\dots+r_nx_n=0\}$ , if $m>n$ then $A$ as a matrix has $m$ rows and $n$ columns and I wanted to use that to some how find a $\hat{F}$ but couldn't find a way to use the "Artinian" condition.
Any help or hint is appreciated.
